# Corona SDK - Cancel timer from within Widget Candy button onPress handler

Tags: timer, event-handling, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to cancel a timer within the onPress event handler of a Widget Candy button. However, the timerId is always nil even though I have defined it as a local variable within the file scope. I am new to Lua development so I am assuming that this issue has to do with variable scope but I am having difficulty figuring out a way to access the timer variable without making it a true global variable (i.e. declaring it without the "local" keyword). See the code snippet below.

```
local countdownTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, handleCountdownTimer, countdown);

local answerButton1 = wcandy.NewButton
{
x       = "center",
y       = "55%",
width   = "75%",
name    = "MyButton1",
theme   = "theme_1",
border     = {"normal",6,1, .12,.12,0,.4,  .72,.72,.72,.6},
pressColor = {1,1,1,.25},
caption = "Touch me!",
textAlign   = "center",
fontSize    = "40",
onPress     =   function( EventData )
                    timer.cancel(countdownTimer); -- "countdownTimer" is always nil!!!
                    local button = wcandy.GetHandle("MyButton1");
                    if button:get("caption") == tostring(solution) then
                        questionText:set("caption", "Correct!");
                    else
                        questionText:set("caption", "Wrong!");
                    end
                end
}
```

Comment: One thing I just thought of: what makes you say "countdownTimer is always nil!!!" at the cancel line, if it is an error message can your print it, or did you have a print statement just before timer.cancel?

Comment: @Scholli - I am using the Lua Glider IDE and I can inspect the variable with the debugger. The variable shows as nil and also reports the following error when I try to execute it anyway: ?:0: attempt to index a nil value
message
stack traceback:
 ?: in function <?:218>
 [C]: ?
 ?: in function 'cancel'
 ...nk(builds)\sampleblank(default)\sampleblank\main.lua:40: in function 'onPress'
 ...eblank(default)\sampleblank\scripts\widget_candy.lua:913: in function <...eblank(default)\sampleblank\scripts\widget_candy.lua:869>
 ?: in function <?:218>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with the code you posted: your countdownTimer should be non-nil when the onPress gets called. You should not have to test if countdownTimer is nil. Print countdownTimer after you create it to confirm it is not nil before you create the new button. Also search the code to find all places the variable is referenced and check if any of them set it to nil.

**Update:**

One thing you could try is moving the function and make it local:

```
local countdownTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, handleCountdownTimer, countdown);

local function cancelTimer( EventData )
    timer.cancel(countdownTimer); -- "countdownTimer" is always nil!!!
    local button = wcandy.GetHandle("MyButton1");
    if button:get("caption") == tostring(solution) then
        questionText:set("caption", "Correct!");
    else
        questionText:set("caption", "Wrong!");
    end
end

local answerButton1 = wcandy.NewButton
{
x       = "center",
y       = "55%",
width   = "75%",
name    = "MyButton1",
theme   = "theme_1",
border     = {"normal",6,1, .12,.12,0,.4,  .72,.72,.72,.6},
pressColor = {1,1,1,.25},
caption = "Touch me!",
textAlign   = "center",
fontSize    = "40",
onPress     = cancelTimer
}
```

**Update 2** (after @husterk found the above still doesn't work):

I can't see anything wrong so I have tested this in my corona sim and there is no problem with it, so the issue is elsewhere. Here is the main.lua in its entirety:

```
local widget = require('widget')

local function handleCountdownTimer(event)
    print('timed out; timer:', event.source)
end

local countdownTimer

local function cancelTimer( event )
    print('cancelling timout, timer:', countdownTimer)
    timer.cancel(countdownTimer) 
end

local answerButton1 = widget.newButton
{
    onPress     = cancelTimer, 
    width = 100,
    height = 100,
    label = 'hello',
    emboss = true
}

countdownTimer = timer.performWithDelay(10000, handleCountdownTimer)
print('timer started:', countdownTimer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the countdownTimer is definitely nil within the onPress handler. However, if I execute the same timer.cancel(countdownTimer) function in the main file scope everything works fine. It seems as if event handlers are running in a different scope (kind of like events in .NET that run on a separate thread from the UI thread).

Comment: The update results in the same issue. I am beginning to wonder if the issue is caused by the Widget Candy button object. I am going to test a standard button as well. I will let you know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I just tested canceling a timer from a standard button event handler and the same issue occurs. I am at a loss...

Comment: I've put an example that works. There is nothing wrong with the code you show so the problem is somewhere else, you must be deleting it somewhere. As state in my answer, search for all occurences. Also, see update.

Comment: This is strange. So if you declare the countdownTimer local variable prior to actually settings the value with the timer.performWithDelay function then everything works. However, if you assign the variable on the same line as the timer.performWithDelay function then it breaks. Is there some reason for this?

Comment: FYI... In your example the countdownTimer is nil in the handleCountdownTimer function. You have to use event.source to get the handle to the timer in order for the example to fully work.

Comment: @husterk about nil countdownTimer this is normal because only "up values" (vars declared before a function) are visible to the function.

Comment: @husterk about the same line question: I can't think of why this would happen. I know local a=f(a) would not work as one might expect but that does not apply in the case of timer.

Comment: I guess I will just start declaring all my locals first prior to use so that I don't run into this issue again. Hopefully someone will be able to explain this scope / declaration issue at some point. Thanks for all your help. I will mark this solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try cancelling like this:

```
if(countdownTimer~=nil)  -- Check whether timer is triggering or not 
  timer.cancel(countdownTimer)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does not help. I need to be able to stop the timer as soon as the button is pressed. I can't skip stopping the timer as I can see that it is still running even though the countdownTimer reference is showing as nil within the onPress event handler.

Comment: Try this

    local tm
    local number = 0


    function fn_counter()
      number = number + 1
     txt_counter.text = number
     if number >= 10 then
 
  timer.cancel(tm)
 
 end
end

tm = timer.performWithDelay(1000, fn_counter, 0)